# MAX function in MySQL does not return proper key value

Tags: mysql, max

I have a table called `tbl_user_sal`:

```
| id | user_id | salary |    date    |
| 1  |    1    |  1000  | 2014-12-01 |
| 2  |    1    |  2000  | 2014-12-02 |
```

Now I want to get the id of the maximum date. I used the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(date) AS from_date, id, user_id, salary
FROM tbl_user_sal
WHERE user_id = 1
```

But it gave me this output:

```
| id | user_id | salary | from_date  |
| 1  |    1    |  2000  | 2014-12-02 |
```

Which is correct as far as the max date being `2014-12-02`, but the corresponding id is not correct. This happens for other records as well. I used order by to check but that was not successful either. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Note: Its not necessary that max date will have max `id`, according to my needs. Records can have max date but `id` may be older.

Comment: there is no such field `awrd_date` in your table and the output can not be what you said.

Comment: @Begueradj thank you for pointing the mistake, i changed my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to retrieve that information for a single user, which you seem to, because of your `WHERE` clause, just use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_user_sal
WHERE user_id = 1
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If you want to do that for every user, however, you will have to get a little bit fancier. Something like that should do it:

```
SELECT t2.id, user_id, date
--find max date for each user_id
FROM (SELECT user_id, MAX(date) AS date
      FROM tbl_user_sal
      GROUP BY user_id) AS t1
--join ids for each max date/user_id combo
JOIN tbl_user_sal AS t2
  USING (user_id, date)
--limit to 1 id for every user_id
GROUP BY
  user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing group by clause Try this:

```
select max(awrd_date) as from_date,awrd_id 
from tbl_user_sal 
where awrd_user_id = 106
group by awrd_id
```

Comment: It's not the case that the `max(awrd_date)` and `awrd_id` will be from the same row.

Comment: I guess OP needs max by date and not by both see he says "1       1       2000    2014-12-02" is correct by date but his id is getting messed up. He was expecting it as 2 which is correct.

Comment: "Which is correct in sense of date as "2014-12-02" is max. But its corresponding Id is not correct. " --- that's right, and your query will also mix data from different rows as well.

Comment: @almasshaikh , i used "group by" in the query but it give all the result grouped on the basis of the date, which is not what i required.

Comment: @Purushottamzende I dont think it should group by date as i asked SQL engine to group by id. I think you have a typo in your query if you see that?

Comment: @almasshaikh , can you plz explain more on what u mean by "typo in your query". or provide me any link or ref ..

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you should do here is have a subquery that pulls the max date, and your outer query looks for the row with that date.

It looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM myTable);
```

Additional things may need to be added if you want to search for a specific user_id, or get the largest date for each user_id, but this gives your expected results for this example here.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07f420/1).